# Error Opencv FacemarkLBF external symbol not solved LNK2019

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection, unresolved-external

I'm trying to do a face detection followed by a facemark detection. I always encounter the same errors with all the attempts I make and can't find any information on the internet.
The errors are :

- `Error LNK2019 external symbol not resolved "public: __cdecl cv::face::FacemarkLBF::Params::Params(void)" (??0Params@FacemarkLBF@face@cv@@QEAA@XZ)`
- `Error LNK2019 external symbol not resolved "public: static struct cv::Ptr<class cv::face::FacemarkLBF> __cdecl cv::face::FacemarkLBF::create(struct cv::face::FacemarkLBF::Params const &)" (?create@FacemarkLBF@face@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VFacemarkLBF@face@cv@@@3@AEBUParams@123@@Z)`

```
    Ptr<Facemark> facemark;
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector;
    faceDetector.load("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Test\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

    string LBF = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Test\\lbfmodel.yaml";

    FacemarkLBF::Params params = FacemarkLBF::Params();

    facemark = FacemarkLBF::create(params);
    facemark->loadModel(LBF);
    
    cout << "Loaded Model" << endl;
```

I then launch the detection in the process function with the facedetector but the problem does not come from there.

Comment: which compiler do you use, and what do you link ? some version of opencv_face.lib seems missing in your project

Comment: also, did you build the opencv libs from src, with contrib modules ? (else you won't have that lib)

Comment: This is maybe the lib missing. But I don't know how to find it. I have only opencv_world454.lib and opencv_world454d.lib

Comment: I use VS 2019 to compile my program

Comment: again, you need to build from src, with contrib modules, to get the required opencv_face.lib (which contains the code for the landmarks)